# How do I render @font-face in PhantomJS screen capture?

Tags: font-face, phantomjs

The screen capture is great, but the custom @font-face fonts aren't being rendered.  Is it possible to correct this?

Comment: I'm using phantomjs 1.9.7 and still face this issue, did you figure out any solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

After doing some research for a bit I found this

http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=247

Looks like SVG works the best.

One problem I ran into while testing a screenshot again after using an SVG version of the font was WebKit caching the old page and still showing the broken fonts. Make sure your server explicitly tells it to not use a cached version, or clean WebKits cache.

Comment: This problem still exists and using SVG is a working solution. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

I've build PhantomJS with Webfonts support for OSX and Linux - You can use the binaries directly -

Download From: http://arunoda.me/blog/phantomjs-webfonts-build.html

Comment: @David, it's working for me on one font and not another. Adobe's Source Sans Pro is working, the custom icons via IcoMoon are not working.

Comment: @Arunoda-Susiripala  could you please update the link to the original solution that you used to compile those binarie, referenced in your blog?